# certain section's permalinks are throwing a 404

Tags: wordpress, content-type

We have migrated our WP site to new hosting and since then one section using custom content types manager is throwing a 404. The other ~4 work correctly.

I have cleared the plugin's cache and imported the .json file correctly.

When I change the permalinks to default from post name they load properly. Any idea on how to get this section working?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem you're facing on  Post name permalinks. Save that option again. If it not working,
select custom structure and give index.php as a prefix

eg: `/index.php/%postname%/`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but we're getting the same 404 error both by trying to reset the post name and also with the custom structure.